# Opencv - Overlay image without cvAddWeighted

Tags: c++, image, opencv

there are plenty of tutorials showing how to blend two images in opencv:

- http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html
- http://aishack.in/tutorials/transparent-image-overlays-in-opencv/

But all of them are based on this equation:

[opencv blending http://opencv.itseez.com/_images/math/afeb868ed1632ace1fe886b5bfbb6fd933b742b8.png](http://opencv.itseez.com/_images/math/afeb868ed1632ace1fe886b5bfbb6fd933b742b8.png)

which means that I will be combining two images by averaging them and consequently I'll be **loosing intensity** on both images.

For instance, let *alpha = 0.5, f0(x) = 255, and f1(x) = 0*. After applying this equation, the result image *g(x) = 127*. That is not what I need. The first image should remain unchanged. And the transparency must be applied in the second one.

**My problem is:**

the first image f0(x) should not be changed and an alpha should be applied to the second image f1(x) when it overlays the first image f0(x).

I cannot figure out how to do this. Any help?

Comment: Everyone who landed on this post should probably read [the answer over there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49180468/176769).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, alpha channels are not supported by OpenCV. From the `imread` documentation:
**Note that in the current implementation the alpha channel, if any, is stripped from the output image. For example, a 4-channel RGBA image is loaded as RGB if `flags > 0`.**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451021/alpha-channel-in-opencv) SO post for a possible work around using imagemagick.

Hope that is helpful!

Comment: thank you @mevatron for pointing me towards ImageMagick. here is the answer: composite -dissolve 50% meme1.png meme2.png result.png. It is also possible to code in c++ using Magick++.