# Addition of two images using knowing specific points of addition in OpenCV using python

Tags: python, image, opencv, addition

I am trying to add two images of different sizes using bitwise operations in OpenCV using python. I want a particular point in Image1(an image of face of a person) to coincide with a particular point in Image2(image of a spectacle frame). The particular points are not the cornermost points of the images.I know the 2 mid points of the frame glasses and the pupil of the eyes. I want the frame mid points to coincide with the pupil points of the eyes in the face. The code which I am using adds the second image's leftmost corner point to the specific point of Image1 as in Line 10, whereas i want the mid point of left glass frame to be added.

The face image can be any random image and the spectacle image is as -

[image: Image 2]

I am using the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_frame = cv2.imread('image1.jpg',1)
img_in = cv2.imread('face.jpg',1)
new_image = np.zeros(img_frame.shape,dtype=np.uint8)

i,j,k = img_frame.shape

for ii in range (1,i):
    for jj in range (1,j):
        pixel = img_frame[ii,jj]

        img_in[339+ii,468+jj] = pixel

cv2.imwrite('pc2_with_frame_7.jpg',img_in)            
cv2.imshow('win',img_in)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow('win')
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to calculate the x-distance between the pupils and the x-distance between the centres of the glasses and scale the glasses by that ratio to fit the face width.

Comment: You'll also need to calculate whether the eyes are level, i.e. if the y-coordinates of the two eyes are the same, if not, you will need to calculate the y-difference between the eyes and divide it by the x-difference, take the tan inverse and use that angle to rotate the glasses.

Comment: yes, scaling part is already done, This is the next problem, that is to place it at corect place

Comment: Will you change the glasses picture to be a PNG, which will support transparency (whereas JPEGs do not) and allow the eyes to show through?

Comment: yes,I would like the eyes to be shown or it can only be the opaque part or just the frame of the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it seems nobody else much can help so I will offer what I can...

What you are trying to do is called alpha-compositing. You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) on Wikipedia and also [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) in the OpenCV documentation.

My tool of choice for this would be ImageMagick, which is free and has Perl, Python, C/C++ bindings as well as command-line tools. If I start with this photo (face.jpg):

[image]

and take your glasses.jpg file and convert it to a PNG with transparency, whcih looks like this:

[image]

I can run the following ImageMagick command at the Terminal

```
composite glasses.png face.jpg out.jpg
```

and I get this:

[image]

It seems that OpenCV has problems maybe with transparency, and a solution is presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451021/alpha-channel-in-opencv). If you want to try the masking method suggested by @ypnos in that post, I have made you the necessary input files and you can download them from my website at:

[glasses.png with alpha channel](http://www.thesetchells.com/glasses.png)

[input-mask.png](http://thesetchells.com/input-mask.png)

Comment: I was able to convert the file into .png but was not able to extract alpha channel using - 

convert input.png -channel Alpha -negate -separate input-mask.png

Comment: How does your glasses.png look like that? Did you edit the image? How did you do that?I am not able to remove the white pixels from the background

Comment: I loaded your glasses.jpg into Photoshop and used  Select->Color Range to select the black frames, then I inverted the selection so I had the "white/clear" areas selected then I deleted the selection so it looks like a chessboard and saved as PNG because that format supports transparency.

Comment: You do not need to extract the alpha channel, and indeed you cannot extract the alpha channel from a file that was a JPEG since JPEGs cannot contain transparency.